# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this._postBackSettings.async' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have report on my asp page and every time I change a filter and click view report, I get this error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this._postBackSettings.async' is null or not an object

I tried change the EnablePartialRendering="true" to EnablePartialRendering="false" but then people can't login on the site

Comment: is this sql reporting services? Can you give a little moreinfo?

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I am using Reporting Services 2008 and the new report viewer control.  My report page is inside a Master Page, and my master page has a script manager on it.

Answer (score 4):

I discovered another solution to this problem.

I use the Telerik RadScriptManager and RadAjaxManager (which are built upon the respective ASP.NET framework objects).  I discovered some issues when I implemented JQuery UI animations to hide the buttons--animations which I executed "OnClientClick" of the button.

To solve the problem, I handled the OnRequestStart and OnResponseEnd client events and executed the applicable hide and show animations from OnRequestStart and OnResponseEnd, respectively.

I know not everyone uses Telerik, but this concept might be key, and probably applies to other AJAX frameworks: When performing client-side changes on ajaxified elements (especially changes like animations which occur during AJAX request processing), make those changes in  your framework's RequestStart/ResponseEnd client side event handlers rather than in the client side event handlers of the ajaxified elements.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem and haven't really found any satisfying solution until I ended up on https://siderite.dev/blog/thispostbacksettingsasync-is-null-or.html which does exactly what I want.

Just to avoid problems with possible dead links in the future, here is the code:

```
var script = @"
if (Sys &&
    Sys.WebForms && Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager &&
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance) 
{
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm &&
       !prm._postBackSettings)
    {
        prm._postBackSettings = prm._createPostBackSettings(false, null, null);
    }";

ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(
    Page, 
    Page.GetType(), 
    "FixPopupFormSubmit", 
    script);
```

In case of a submit without the _postBackSettings being set it creates them, causing the null reference exception to disappear as _postBackSettings.async is then available.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solved by setting `EnablePartialRendering` to false of `ScriptManager`.

```
ScriptManager1.EnablePartialRendering  = false;
```

In `OnInit` event of the page where `rsweb:ReportViewer` is used.
If you want to enable for other page then set it true on master page's `OnInit`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the button inside a panel (not update panel), then add this line to the panel
DefaultButton="Button1"

This will avoid the error.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, although in my case there were no reports involved: it was a just a normal asp.net page with an image button. The thing was that on client click I was cancelling the next javascript events with this code:

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
if (event.stopPropagation)
    event.stopPropagation();
```

I removed the code and the problem also disapeared. My guess is that asp.net ajax needs to do some processing on client click and maybe your report control is doing something like I was doing. Hope it helps you find your problem and sorry for my english :)
Regards,
MMM

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem just now and found a solution by accident.

Problem started showing up after I moved the ScriptManager to a master page - and only when I was using pages with no update panels.

Solved it by moving the ScriptManager tag to just in front of the content area of the master page.

JavaScript ordering problems?

Comment: Very strange, but your comment just fixed the very same problem I had with master pages and pages with no update panels.
Thanks!